# Getting error : Must construct a QGUIApplication first

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qprocess, qt5.9

I am developing a GUI application, but whenever I am trying to close the application, it throws an error that "Must construct QGuiapplication first". My main is not returning exit code 0, so it's not exiting normally. I think some destructor is getting called twice but need some help here. I am attaching main.cpp code here for reference.

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QFontDatabase>
#include <QtWebEngine>

#include "ApplicationManager.h"
#include "AppLogger.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseOpenGLES);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QtWebEngine::initialize();

    app.setApplicationName("MCS3.0");
    QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/Fonts/Roboto.ttf");

#ifdef VERSION
    app.setApplicationVersion(QString("%1").arg(VERSION));
    logInfoMessage(app.applicationName()+app.applicationVersion()+" Started");
#endif

    ApplicationManager::instance().run();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Is that error message completed? because I can't find it in the source code.

Comment: @Jiu still there.

Comment: I mean Qt source code, I only found https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/c5307203f5c0b0e588cc93e70764c090dd4c2ce0/src/widgets/kernel/qapplication.cpp#L130

Comment: Please edit your question to show the *exact* error message.  These types of messages are usually the result of trying to create/initialize an instance of a `QObject` derived class *before* `main` has begun -- usually a static global of some description defined elsewhere.

Comment: the error message is same which i have posted in the title. @G.M. . Okay, I will look into the code.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant part of the problem is inside `ApplicationManager.h` which was not exposed by OP.

I bet that it makes another instance of `QApplication` (or `QGUIApplication` or `QCoreApplication`).

How can I know this? It's partly a guess (as the name looks like) and partly result of the following test:

`testQApp.cc`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  { QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QLabel qLbl("The app in app");
    qLbl.show();
    app.exec();
  }
  return app.exec();
}
```

`testQApp.pro`:

```
SOURCES = testQApp.cc

QT = widgets
```

Compiled and tested in [cygwin64](http://www.cygwin.org) on Windows 10:

```
$ qmake-qt5 testQApp.pro

$ make

$ ./testQApp
```

[image: snapshot of testQApp]

When I quit the application, the issue occurs:

```
QApplication::exec: Please instantiate the QApplication object first
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

$
```

To make this complete, the relevant paragraph of doc. about [`QApplication`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#details):

> For any GUI application using Qt, there is precisely **one** [QApplication](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html) object, no matter whether the application has 0, 1, 2 or more windows at any given time. For non-[QWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) based Qt applications, use [QGuiApplication](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html) instead, as it does not depend on the [QtWidgets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-module.html) library.

Please, note that the emphasize is *not* done by me.